# Mouse and Keyboard don't work from Shutdown, do work from Restart

Tags: keyboard, uefi, touchpad, 13.10

I have a Lenovo Twist. The Touchpad doesn't work if I start from a cold shutdown. It does work if I restart (I can restart using the touchscreen, which always works). from dmesg the differences in the 2 boots are these files are not loaded off a cold start:

```
[   21.221813]  serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd002a3/0x940300/0x126c00, board id: 2253, fw id: 1192539
[   21.288391] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[   25.907455] psmouse serio2: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=10 00 64, EC=10 00 64
[   21.221827] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[   21.288391] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[   21.360391] inputs:
[   28.169132] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input13
```

Also the psmouse module not loaded. Loading it manually does not fix the problem.  I tried to ssh into the laptop and load the module after a cold start.

In the input devices the Synaptics TouchPad is not there after a cold shutdown.

I am booting from UEFI, not secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

i set "Enabled" the option LaunCMS, then i changed the boot to Legacy only(old-fashion way), and re-install Ubuntu.

This last its because the ubuntu installation under UEFI boot disappeared from boot list, when i choose the Legacy Bios option